# Rendering issues with google maps

Tags: php, google-maps, yii

Using google maps with yii every thing was fine until I changed my classic theme to some other theme now my map is not rendering properly, what could be the problem? any idea?

it is displaying some blocks or you can say map is split. how to avoid this?

http://mobitracktechnologies.in/im/map.png check out how my map is rendering.

I tried some solutions like setting height and width to auto but nothing helped.

this is my div

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:900px;height:500px;"></div>
```

and my map properties

```
 zoom:15,
scaleControl: true,
scrollwheel: true,
zoomControl:false,
```

mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your CSS files and find `box-shadow` related definition.

They might occasionally add shadows to map pieces.